# How do I embed a Google map into a Flash website?

Tags: flash, actionscript, google-maps

I would like to include a Google map in a Flash site I am building. I would like to retain as much of the zoom, print, copy/send url, direction functionality as is practically possible. Please could somebody advise the best way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Google Maps API for Flash](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/)

> This API lets Flex developers embed
>   Google Maps in Flash applications.
>   Similar to the JavaScript version,
>   this ActionScript API provides a
>   number of utilities for manipulating
>   and adding content to maps through a
>   variety of services, enabling you to
>   embed robust, interactive maps
>   applications on your website.

Comment: Thanks Paul. To anybody else wishing to use this, it's worth pointing out though that this API is actionscript 3.0 only – no support for actionscript 2.0 as far as I can tell. If anybody knows of an actionscript 2.0 solution it'd be good to hear about that too.

Comment: Yahoo maps has had a Flash api for some time.  I thought they had it as AS 2, but didn't see it.  For what it's worth,
http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/maps/

Answer (score 1):

[Stamen](http://stamen.com) developed a "BSD-licensed display and interaction library for tile-based maps in Flash (ActionScript 2.0 and ActionScript 3.0) and Python" called [ModestMaps](http://modestmaps.com/)
While not the best choice for Google maps, it also supports Open Street Map, Yahoo, as well as MS maps.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen google maps on flash. May be you can buy some kind of component.